# What algorithm does Google Scholar use to order papers in a search?

Tags: publications, google-scholar

When you perform a search on Google Scholar, is there any detailed explanation of how Google orders the results?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "_Google uses to rank its papers_". You mean those papers authored by Google? Or papers found by Google?

Comment: I've edited to capture the implied question, which I think is now both clear and interesting.

Answer (score 10):

I believe it uses this

> "Google Scholar aims to rank documents the way researchers do,
>   weighing the full text of each document, where it was published, who
>   it was written by, as well as how often and how recently it has been
>   cited in other scholarly literature." [About google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar/about.html)

For more detailed answer,

> "Google Scholar also strengthens the Matthew Effect: articles with
>   many citations will be more likely to be displayed in a top position,
>   get more readers and receive more citations, which then consolidate
>   their lead over articles that are cited less often." [Google Scholar‘s
>   Ranking Algorithm: An Introductory Overview](https://www.gipp.com/wp-content/papercite-data/pdf/beel09.pdf)